# How to choose between multiple Nash equilibria and solution concepts?

Tags: game-theory

Please help!  I don't remember what happened last night but I woke up this morning in a prison cell with nothing but my pile of game theory lecture notes. The guard came in and says they have another rational person in the cell next door, and we both have to play a one-shot nonzero-sum matrix game without communicating.    (The utilities include various prison-themed events like early release, food, being beaten with sticks etc.)

Using the algorithms from these books, I've worked though the game matrix and found it has several Nash equilibria.   Some of them have various 'solution concept' properties like being trembling hand perfect or evolutionarily stable. Some have higher overall social utilities and some have more egalitarian outcomes.

My question then is: which of these equilibria should I choose to actually play?

My pile of lecture notes don't seem to say anything very helpful about this, instead they all have vague statements like 'solution concepts might explain some choices seen in the world'.   I don't care about explaining what is seen in the world, I want to know the optimal action to take right now.

In particular -- some of the N equilibria here are mixed strategies and some of the others are pure.   If no-one gives me any better advice, I'm going to default to picking one of the strategies completely at random (ie. with 1/N probability).   However if I do this, I'm effective creating and using a new mixed strategy with new action weights, which wasn't in the original set, and therefore isn't optimal any more?   Can anyone explain if this is a good idea or not, and why?   And why are all the authors of these lecture notes avoiding these questions?

Comment: Your question is too general. I think you need to provide an actual example game to illustrate what you're not sure about.

Comment: As far as your question "why are all the authors of these lecture notes avoiding these questions?", you should give a reference. Which authors, which lecture notes?

Comment: thanks -- I'm interested in the general question, but we could take the standard battles the sexes game as an example - and its wikipedia page as an example of its presentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_sexes_%28game_theory%29).    Here we have a matrix (((3,2),(0,0)),((0,0),(3,2))).   There are three equilibria: the two pure cases (3,2) and (2,3), and one mixed, where each player picks their best event with p=3/5.   Which of the three should I actually choose?  And why does the wikipedia article not give this answer, and instead just discusses ways to modify the game?

Comment: (Also using this to illustrate the effect of picking an equilibrium at random:   if I choose from the three with probability 1/3 for each, then I get probabilities of (1/3)+(1/3 * 3/5)  and (1/3)+(1/3 * 2/5)  for my two actions, which equals 0.53 and 0.46.   This is a new mixed strategy but is not one of the original equilibria; so should I play it? )

Answer (score 3):

Most of game theory concerns *interacting agents*: what is optimal for you to do depends on what your opponent does (and vice versa). Thus, most of  game theory focuses on equilibria, interpreted as profiles of strategies were all agents are playing optimally *given how their opponents are playing*.

There are classes of games where it is possible to recommend an essentially unique strategy; e.g., zero-sum games. It is often possible to pinpoint strategies that one should *not* play; e.g., avoid strictly dominated strategies. But in general examples (including Battle of Sexes), there is no overarching principle when you try to solve the problem of what to do in isolation.

Finally, if you are really interested in a theory that selects a unique strategy profile for every game, you should read J. C. Harsanyi and R. Selten. *A General Theory of Equilibrium Selection in Games*. Cambridge, MA: The MIT Press, 1988. Beware: their advice is going to work in general only if it is common knowledge that you and your opponents have read the same book, understood its contents, and decided to follow its recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen Harsanyi&Selten mentioned before so I should check this out.    But as I understand your answer, it's only going to provide yet another 'convention' which like all the other conventions will only work if I make those extra assumptions that the other player is using them. (So is still useless in my prison example?)

Comment: As I currently understand things, there's a couple of clear ways to remove some equilibria to start, such as all those dominated by others, and non-symmetric ones if the game is symmetric.   But then there is a whole host of suggestions for selection such as: total utility max, risk minisimation, basin side, evolutionalry stable; trembling-hand optimal, or totally arbitrary conventions like assume we use the actions starting with the first letter in the alphabet.  But there's no way to know which of all these the other person will use?   So what should I actually do in my prison example?

Comment: One idea I'm currently playing with is: if I start with the 'meta'-strategy of picking a random strategy from all the non-dominated ones, then as in my previous BoS example, I can show this is equivalent to a new mixed strategy which is not itself an equilibrium.   But, I could use fictitious play from that point to land in the nearest basin equilibrium. And if all players followed the same logic then we could cooperate.  To mind this seems more 'rational' than some of the other 'solution concepts' but it is really just another one to add to that pile ?

Comment: Fictitious play is not guaranteed to converge.

Comment: Good point mic!   Maybe I can work around this though; AFAIK the non-convergent cases are when we start with pure strategies, like in scissors/paper/stone.    I can't prove this but my intuition (probably based on empirical work with variational Bayes?) is that if I start with a mixture containing at least some of each non-stupid action, then I will get some better convergence guarantee ? Does that sound any better ?  I need to actually choose an action in the next few hours when that prison guard comes back and all I currently still have are 'debates' about 'solution concepts' ...  :-)

Comment: Be bayesian: assess the probability that each solution concept works best (given your predicament) and maximise expected utility. After all, your suggestion to put equal probability on each "non-stupid actions" is equivalent to using equal probabilities.

Comment: I hope you get an amnesty for trying hard  ;-)

Comment: Arrg! They are hitting me with sticks now, no-one gave me the rational decision!

Answer (score 2):

There exist a several solution concepts, for this situation, but don´t exist any "universal", valid for all types of games. Operation is limited to situations where everyone is guided by the same principle.
Simple examples of principles.

1. If unique NE from set of NE is Pareto dominant, use it (that mean,
   that this equilibrium gives every player at least as much as the
   other equilibrium)

   2. If unique NE from NE set is efficient, use it. (NE, which maximizes a sum of payoffs)
   3. Use a symmetric NE, if exist (especially, for a symmetric game really exist, but no necessarry pure)
   4. If you play repeatedly, watch where the NE game converges and use it first

But these concepts are not universal . For example, a Chicken game:

$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2/2 & 5/0\\
0/5 & -10/-10
\end{array}\right)$$

The simple 2x2 symmetric game has a 2 efficent equilibria $(5,0)$ and $(0,5)$ and one (worse) symmetric mixed equilibrium. But the goal of the game is to force the opponents to accept the equilibrium $ (5,0) $, a vice versa.

Appendix: (Reply to comment, but contains a picture)

Experimentally one has proved, that the final used equilibrium  is not predictable. From example, an experimental game of 7 players, from *Camerer-Behavioral game theory. Experiments in strategic interaction*, page  13-15, has a many of NE, but exactly two symmetric: 3 with payoff 60 for every player and 12 with payoff 112 for every player.

Experimental results with repeated game and accross groups are here[image] Decision between 12 and 3 is unpredictable! Despite the fact that 12 dominates 3. 
Note: In this game, payoff to player *i* has been a function of strategy of *i* and **median** strategy. Use 12 against median 3 leeds to payoff -100

Comment: Thanks - yes (1) seems very rational, and also its more general version, of removing all NE's that are dominated by any others, leaving some set of non-dominated NEs to choose from.    (2) feels fairly rational though a bit less so: if the other player is identical to me then we have to choose the same solution in a symmetric game.  (3 is not relevant in my case).     But generally -- say I want to write a Python function that takes the game matrix as input and return the optimal strategy (rather than some set of NEs) -- what should I do? Is this formally uncomputable? Do I pick one at random?

Comment: Another text example, from Rasmusen:  'the best prediction in Chicken is perhaps the mixed-strategy equilibrium, because its symmetry makes it a focal point of sorts, and does not require any differences between the players.'    Again I am worried about the vague words like 'perhaps' and 'of sorts' when I am looking for a rigourous mathematical optimum ?